# Что такое интеграционное тестирование?

Tags: тестирование

Помогите разобраться в интеграционном тестирование. Если материалов по юнит-тестированию довольно много, то толковых примеров по интеграционному тестированию не нашел.

конкретно по задаче, как можно протестировать код который:

- подготавливает данные
- обрабатывает их в цикле
- результаты распределяет по разным таблицам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интеграционное тестирование отличается от модульного тестирования тем, что:

- **во-первых**, вы будете тестировать не каждый модуль (класс, блок) в отдельности, а несколько модулей совместно. В процессе интеграционного тестирования (в отличие от модульного) Ваши IoC-контейнеры будут передавать в качестве зависимостей не моки (заглушки), а настоящие объекты. К примеру, если вы тестируете метод класса, осуществлающий фильтрацию полученных из БД объектов, то в случае с модульным тестированием, вы должны будете исключить работу с реальной БД с целью ускорения прохождения теста и для того, чтобы гарантировать, что результат выполнения теста будет проверять только функционал тестироемого класса и конкретного его метода.
- **во-вторых** тем, что на интеграционное тестирование не обязательно накладываются ограничения по времени выполения (иными словами, никому не нужен модульный тест, который будет выполняться, скажем, минуту, что вполне приемлемо для интеграционного теста). Это опять же связано с тем, что в процессе интеграционного тестирования ваш код будет работать, например, с реальной БД, запрос к которой будет занимать определённое время.

*По вашему конкретному примеру,* если код изначально написан так, что его можно тестировать, то, в общем случае, у Вас будет три-четыре отдельных класса, каждый из которых будет отвечать за выполнение конкретной задачи (согласно принципу [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), т.е. за подготовку данных, обработку данных, распределение данных, запись данных в БД. Т.е. каждый из этих классов должен пользоваться функционалом другого класса так, чтобы его можно было легко заменить иной реализацией. Т.е. подставить как реальный объект другого класса, так и заглушку, тогда интеграционное тестирование - это то же модульное тестирование, но с передачей реальных зависимостей. Здесь на помощь приходит [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Мне не понятно, что можно считать успешным прохождением теста? В случае с юнит-тестированием есть эталонные данные, и мы заранее знаем что ожидаем от метода. В случае фильтрации данных из базы, что будет критерием успешности? Нашел/не-нашел? Но тогда в чем смысл тестирования?

Comment: Критерий успешности прохождения теста зависит от спецификации - от того, какого результата вы ждёте от конкретного модуля, в случае с интеграционным тестированием - чего Вы ждёте в качестве результата работы нескольких модулей в связке. Смысл интеграционного тестирования - убедиться в том, что модули корректно отрабатывают в процессе взаимодействия между собой, а не по отдельности. К примеру, критерием успешности  тестирования класса, выполняющего фильтрацию данных может быть проверка на то, какие данные найдены, и нет ли там лишних данных. Это уже Вам на откуп как разработчику.